# toString(int variable, n) vs toString()

Tags: java

I have been looking for the answer this question everywhere and I don't know what it is called, but what is the point of a toString method with a variable in its parenthesis?

```
public static String toString(Student[] list, int n)
   {

   }
```

I cannot find this answer for some reason. I didn't know you can provide input to a toString, as I thought that you didn't call the method directly, you would just print a string whenever you declare the class it is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toString()` is just a method like anything else. It just so happens that the `toString()` method with no arguments gets called automatically by a lot of things, like when trying to print out an object. However, that does not prevent you from making another method named `toString(int variable)`. That method will never be called automatically, but you can still declare it and call it yourself if you want to do custom string manipulation in whatever program you are writing.

Comment: So you're saying that as soon as you put a variable inside the parenthesis, the computer automatically stops declaring this method when you say System.out.print(class), and instead calls it as a normal method? This project is on recursion btw if it gives you more info

Comment: I'm saying that this method has absolutely nothing to do with the normal toString() method. It will never be called automatically by print() statements, or anything else. It is just a normal method that returns a String and happens to have the same name. The normal toString() method with no arguments will still always be called by java for use in print() statements, and anything else.

Comment: I don't understand why my professor named it this then, we were never taught about regular String methods(which I assume are just methods that return Strings?)

Comment: Yeah String methods are just methods which return strings. I don't know why he named it that either - perhaps it has some logical relation to the normal toString() method? Where is it called? What does it do? I'm just guessing, but my best guess is that he named it that to show that it was in some way related to the normal toString() method. Either way, you can name a method anything you want, so choosing a good name is basically a matter of opinion. In my opinion, your professor's name choice is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide any parameters to any method, but `toString` is special in that it's used in a lot of the inner workings of Java.

That said...this is *not* that `toString` method.  The one you wish to *override* takes no parameters whatsoever.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // implementation
}
```

A `toString` that takes parameters implies that the object doesn't have enough information to print about itself, which is contradictory, so this method would like be best renamed to something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

toString() can be over ridden in your specific class,

something like

```
public class ToStringEg {

private Student[] list;

private int n;

public ToStringEg(Student[] list, int n) {
    super();
    this.list = list;
    this.n = n;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    // You can access list and v varible required by you
    //finally create a buf based on your logic
    return buf.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `toString()` method has totally different from the special method `@Override public String toString()` inherited from `Object` class.

I think you should change your method name to avoid confusion in future.

How `toString()` method automatically called during `System.out.println()` or `String.valueOf(obj)`? *NO MAGIC!* Just see the implementation of `valueOf()` method in `String` class.

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Comment: I can't unfortunately, my professor gave the method as a given, and she would take points off if it was named different

Comment: Well.... It's not mandatory at all. But if you tried to  write ``public static String toString()`` i.e. without param, you will face some problem like ``cannot hide the instance method``.